# Content-Security-Policy to make Tensorflow.js's WASM backend work (Chrome 91.0.4472.77, macOS 11.3.1)

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy, tensorflow.js

Latest Chrome update breaks WASM backend when using Tensorflow.js. Apparently, browser enforces more strict Content-Security-Policy headers now.

Gist of the error (from console):

```
"Initialization of backend wasm failed"

"Error: Failed to construct 'Worker': Access to the script at 'blob:https://fiddle.jshell.net/c95fbade-77fe-4945-a4dc-25a3a19f97d6' is denied by the document's Content Security Policy.
```

Curious if anyone figured out a way to run it?

Browser/OS -  **Chrome 91.0.4472.77 / macOS Big Sur 11.3.1**

To check out error go here - https://jsfiddle.net/alex_oliynyk/2b6oa4dm/14/

Cheers!

Comment: Browser can't enforces more strict Content-Security-Policy header since you publish this header, browser just follow it. Why don't you just add `blob:` into `worker-src` or `script-src` directive (which one you do use in CSP)?

Comment: @granty thanks for the suggestion. Tried, it didn't work. Also adding all kind of `unsafe-*` and '*' to script-src failed me as well

Comment: There are 4 fixes connected with Content-Security-Policy in the latest Chrome - https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2021/05/stable-channel-update-for-desktop_25.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question got [answered](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/5137#issuecomment-850646000) in the Tensorflow.js repo. I'll repost the solution here in case anyone has the same issue.

1. CSP headers to help:

```
'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy': 'require-corp',
'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy': 'same-origin',
```

Still, after figuring out CSP headers Tensorflow.js did not work. Threw an error connected to SIMD.

2. This appears to fix it for the time being:

```
tf.ENV.set('WASM_HAS_SIMD_SUPPORT', false);
tf.ENV.set('WASM_HAS_MULTITHREAD_SUPPORT', false);
```

It disables SIMD support and cuts performance, thus I hope it will be fully addressed in the future versions of the lib.

Cheers,